# Is there a name for the set defined by the Minkowski sum of circles in orthogonal planes?

Tags: geometry, vectors, mathematical-physics, harmonic-analysis

Recently, I started thinking about the set of points defined by the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of 1D circles in orthogonal planes. The reason for this is to extend the well known result that 1D linear/harmonic oscillators are equivalent to uniform circular motions in the 2D plane, projected onto a line. Generalizing this, it is possible to think of *n*-dimensional harmonic oscillators as projections of the sum of uniform motions on *n* circles in *n* orthogonal planes in an (*n*+1)-dimensional Euclidean space with a common vertical axis. To illustrate this construction in the *n*=2 case, I have created an animated GIF showing two unit circles centered at the origin in the *x-z* and *y-z* planes:

[image: Minkowski sum of 2 1D circles in orthogonal planes in 3D]

In this animation, the view rotates to show the same trajectory from two different viewpoints. The second view visually shows the linear projection onto the gray plane. Purple square shows the sum of the projections of the red and blue balls onto this (*x-y*) plane. (There is a random phase shift between the red and blue balls.) More images and animations of this type are posted on my [Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/katchwreck/status/1122258248310984704).

The alignment of the gray ball and the purple square in the projection view visually indicates that 2D linear oscillator motions (purple square) are indistinguishable from projected motions on the 3D surface (gray ball). This is an instance of the property that sums of linear projections of vectors are equivalent to linear projections of sums of  vectors, by linearity of the projection operator. This particular instance of this simple property may be relevant due to the importance of linear/harmonic oscillators in mathematical physics.

By extension, *n*-dimensional oscillators can be thought of as projections of sums of uniform motions on n circles on *n* orthogonal planes in (*n*+1) dimensions. Although unit circles and identical velocities for the uniform circular motions are shown in this animation, the example could easily be generalized to circles with arbitrary radii and points moving with arbitrary fixed velocities.

My questions are:

1. Does the set of points defined by the Minkowski sum of this type of
   arrangement of *n* circles in (*n*+1)-dimensions have a name?
2. If so, are there any references or discussions about its properties
   and potential relevance to physics?

For the sake of clarity, below is some Matlab code to compute a cloud of 3D points representing a finite sample of points in this set, using uniform samples of the two circles:

```
function circle = circle_sum( Npoint )

if nargin < 1 || isempty( Npoint ) 
  Npoint = 4 * 1e3 ; % default number of points per circle
end

circle.x = zeros( Npoint, 3 ) ;
circle.y = zeros( Npoint, 3 ) ;

for kt = 1 : Npoint % generate the 3D coordinates of two 1D circles in orthogonal planes

  tk    = 2 * pi * (kt - 1) / Npoint ; % circle position parameter
  costk = cos( tk ) ; % projection onto the x-y plane
  sintk = sin( tk ) ; % vertical coordinates

  circle.x( kt, : ) = [ costk 0 sintk ] ; % point on circle in the x-z plane 
  circle.y( kt, : ) = [ 0 costk sintk ] ; % point on circle in the y-z plane 

end

circle.sum = zeros( Npoint, Npoint, 3 ) ;

for ks = 1 : Npoint  % points on the Minkowski sum of the circles
  for kt = 1 : Npoint
    circle.sum( kt, ks, : ) = circle.x( ks, : ) + circle.y( kt, : ) ;
  end
end
```

Also, here is some Matlab code to plot this surface from its parametric form:

```
syms s t
x = cos(s) ; y = cos(t) ; z = sin(s) + sin(t) ;
fsurf(x, y, z, [0 2*pi 0 2*pi])
axis square
xlim([-2 2]), ylim([-2 2])
camlight
figSize = 480 ;
az = -35 ;
el = 15 ;
view( az, el ) ;
set( gcf, 'position', [10 10 figSize figSize] )
set( gca, 'xtick', [], 'ytick', [], 'ztick', [] )
```

Resulting image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Minkowski sum of these $2$ circles can be described analytically as the sum :

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos(a)\\\sin(a)\\0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\\sin(b)\\\cos(b)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x=\cos(a)\\y=\sin(a)+\sin(b)\\z=\cos(b)\end{pmatrix}$$

where $a,b$ take all values in $[0,2\pi]$.

We can transform this parametric equation into a cartesian equation

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=2+2 \sin(a) \sin(b)$$

$$x^2+y^2+z^2-2 = \pm 2\sqrt{1-\cos^2(a)}\sqrt{1-\cos^2(b)}$$

$$x^2+y^2+z^2-2 = \pm 2\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-z^2}$$

yielding finally the equivalent quartic equation :

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2-2)^2=4(1-x^2)(1-z^2)$$

Expanded :

$$x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + 2(x^2y^2 - x^2z^2 + y^2z^2) - 4y^2 = 0.$$

Here is a Matlab program that takes profit of this implicit equation using the powerful "isosurface" function (see figure below, of course similar to yours) :

> ```
> clear all;close all;axis equal off
> set(gcf,'color','w');a=1;b=2;axis([-a,a,-a,a,-b,b]);
> I=-a:0.02:a;J=-b:0.02:b;[x,y,z]=meshgrid(I,I,J);
> X=x.^2;Y=y.^2;Z=z.^2;
> e=X.^2+Y.^2+Z.^2+2*X.*Y-2*X.*Z+2*Y.*Z-4*Y;
> [faces,verts,colors] = isosurface(x,y,z,e,0,z);
>    patch('Vertices',verts,'Faces',faces,'FaceVertexCData',colors,'FaceColor','interp','EdgeColor','none');
> alpha(0.2);
> view([130,30]);
> ```

[image]

Comment: Interesting shape, but that is not the same as what I've constructed above. Some differences: 1) it involves the sum of two circles (shown in red and blue in the plot), not three 2) it is a surface, not a solid - considering the boundary of the above solid does not yield the same set of points 3) it is not a convex set - note the indentations near the *x-y* plane, which go all the way in, touching the origin

Comment: I understand : 2 circles instead of 3. Do you confirm that it is circles and not disks ? I will answer you tomorrow (here 2:30 CET).

Comment: Correct - I am taking the sum of two 1D circles in three dimensions, not disks. (Generally, *n* 1D circles in ( *n* + 1 )-D Euclidean space.) The surface is symmetric w.r.t. reflection over the *x-y* plane, & contains the origin. This can be seen by taking one point on the red circle intersecting the *z*-axis at *z* = 1, and adding this to the point on the blue circle intersecting the *z*-axis at *z* = -1 (or vice-versa). The indentations are hard to see above, but the images on my Twitter feed (linked above) show a couple of zoomed-in views near the origin, too. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Analytically, this surface can be described as: $( \cos s , \cos t , \sin s + \sin t )$

Comment: I have corrected my text.

Comment: Nice derivation of the implicit form from the parametric one! Of course, the choice of which axis to put the cosine and the sine terms is arbitrary - hence the different orientations of your plot from mine. It looks like the "ends" of the surface are cut off in your plot, similar to one of the zoomed-in plots on my Twitter feed. I did not know about the Matlab "isosurface" function - thanks! I appreciate your response, but it does not answer either of the two questions listed above (1. does it have a name? 2. are there any references to it in the physics literature?).

Comment: BTW, small typo above - should be $\cos^2 a$ under the square root sign, not $\cos^2 a^2$

Comment: @Daniel Korenblum thanks. Fixed.